# Can't find databases folder in ddms - android

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I'm having a problem with sqlite android. According to the example in [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/), i just have to put my database in the assets folder. I follow it but then, i can't find the databases folder or the sqlite file in the ddms file explorer.

Please tell me whats the problem?

Here is my database code.

```
public class DataBaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/android.qholis.rencanakeuangan/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "MyFinancialPlanning.sqlite";
private static SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
private static DataBaseManager sInstance = null;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DataBaseManager() {
    super(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext(), DB_NAME, null,
            DATABASE_VERSION);
    try {
        createDataBase();
        openDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static DataBaseManager instance() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new DataBaseManager();
    }
    return sInstance;
}

private void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
    } else {
        // By calling this method an empty database will be created into
        // the default system path
        // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
        // database with our database.
        this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.i("DataBaseManager", "DB NOT FOUND");
        // database doesn't exist yet.
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null;
}

public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

private void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public Cursor select(String query) throws SQLException {
    return mDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
}

public Cursor insert(String table, ContentValues values) throws SQLException {
    mDataBase.insert(table, null, values);
    return null;
}

public Cursor delete(String table, String where) throws SQLException {
    mDataBase.delete(table, where, null);
    return null;
}

public Cursor update(String table, ContentValues values, String where) {
    mDataBase.update(table, values, where, null);
    return null;
}

public void sqlCommand(String command) {
    mDataBase.execSQL(command);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (mDataBase != null)
        mDataBase.close();

    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Comment: Did you select your AVD on the left pane? Did you run the app at least once? Do you have your original db in `/assets/`?

Comment: I **strongly** encourage you to [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) rather than the contents of that five-year-old blog post.

Comment: AVD in wich left pane? Sorry, i'm new to eclipse. I run the app million times and i have the db in the assets folder. Can you help? I really appreciate it if you can..

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, but i already have the rest of my app use that code. I only have this database problem, that's all..